# Searching through data with multiple conditions VBA/Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of data with columns indicating the test a product went under and the product. Each product undergoes several tests for example (hot medium cold). If you can imagine, the data for a specific product may look like

```
 A          B
hot      product1
medium   product1
cold     product1
```

I have many products that under went testing so the spreadsheet is extensive (A400 = cold, B400 = productX). What I am trying to do is see if each product underwent the hot medium and cold testing. I made an additional column to eliminate repeated product listing and search the spreadsheet and find the tests (no success). The end goal is to create an additional column with all the parts that did not go through all of the testing.

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you post a sample table of your data? I think an easy `If` statement should work.

Comment: I uploaded an example of what I am trying to do. As you can see in the one posted, sometimes a product will undergo a test more than once. As in the case of product #4, medium was not tested. The code should recognize that products 1-3 had hot, medium, and cold testing and product 4 did not so it should be printed in a new column to report.

Comment: If column D contains the "unduplicated" ("deduplicated"?) list, then a formula in column E2 could be `=IF(OR(COUNTIFS(B:B,D2,A:A,"hot")=0,OR(COUNTIFS(B:B,D2,A:A,"medium")=0,OR(COUNTIFS(B:B,D2,A:A,"cold")=0)),"Not the three bears","all tests done")`  (Sorry, I couldn't resist the Goldilocks reference.)

Comment: I've been trying to mess with what you sent YowE3k but so far excel is erroring out before it runs. I'm thinking a parenthesis is off or something I am just trying to figure out where.

Comment: Why has this received so many down votes? This seems like a pretty legitimate question to me.

Comment: @SandPiper - If I had to guess, I would start with [sample data as image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) and not showing any original effort toward a resolution.

Comment: I apologise, I copy/pasted a bit too much when I was creating the formula in my earlier comment.  As @Jeeped shows in his answer, it should have said `=IF(OR(COUNTIFS(B:B,D2,A:A,"hot")=0,COUNTIFS(B:B,D2,A:A,"‌​medium")=0,COUNTI‌​FS(B:B,D2,A:A,"cold"‌​)=0),"Not the three bears","all tests done")`.

Comment: I apologize to all who felt I didn't put any work into it and down voted this. This is for a proprietary project so I could not just share what I had done, the example I made was just to get the point across of what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you every one for the suggestions you helped me a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Make four new columns with these formulas

C: `COUNTIFS(B:B,$A1,A:A,"hot")`

D: `COUNTIFS(B:B,$A1,A:A,"medium")`

E: `COUNTIFS(B:B,$A1,A:A,"cold")`

These will show you how many times each of those products has been tested in the respective category. Then, use this in the last column:

F: `IF(AND($C1>0,$D1>0,$E1>0,"",$B1)`

This will account for items that were tested in a more than once. If it had a category it was not tested in, it will show you that product name. There might be multiple values in this column.

EDIT: If you absolutely had to have only one column, you could easily combine these together into a superformula.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion SandPiper!